# Is there an algorithm that finds a minimum vertex cover with an approximation factor of 3/2 for a planar graph?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Is there an algorithm that finds a minimum vertex cover with an approximation factor of 3/2
for a planar graph?

Comment: This seems like a HW exercise. The answer is Yes. Use LP rounding + the 4-color theorem.

Comment: Baker's technique can do $1+\varepsilon$ approximation for any $\varepsilon > 0$.